# Dividir los elementos numéricos de una lista por un número determinado en Python

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7

Quiero dividir una lista por un número pero no sé como se pueda hacer hasta ahora hice este código:

```
lista=[] 
n=input('cuantos numeros tendra la lista? ')
for i in range(n): 
  lista.append(input('Elemento para la lista: ')
d=input("Introduzca un divisor: ")
if d != 0:
  p=[int(lista) / d]
  print p 
else: 
print "error"
```

y me devuelve el error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Por ejemplo si doy la siguiente lista

```
[2, 4, 8]
```

con un divisor 2. Me tiene que devolver:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para eso puedes utilizar el método `map` este recibe una función que va a ejecutarse por cada miembro de tu colección de elementos y retorna un nuevo elemento con esto resultado, te quedaría algo así:

```
my_list = [4, 6, 8, 10]
divisor = 2

my_list = list(map(lambda x: x / divisor, my_list))
print(my_list) # [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

El primer argumento es una función lambda que básicamente es una función que se está encargando de dividir cada número entre un divisor especificado, esto retorna una colección por eso tenemos que pasarla a una lista utilizando el método `list`.

Si lo que quieres es un resultado entero en vez de un resultado decimal lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el operador `//` que te retorna un entero, con eso la única variación necesaria a lo que te propongo arriba sería:

```
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x // divisor, my_list))
```

---

El problema que tienes en tu código es que  en:

```
p = [int(lista) / d]
```

estás intentando convertir una lista e.g. `[1, 2, 3]` en un número, y luego dividirla entre en número, lo cual no tiene mucho sentido.

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres dividir una lista, puedes usar

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] /= divisor
```

¿Cual es la diferencia con las otras respuestas?

Esta solución no crea una segunda lista; modifica directamente la lista original. Ventaja: no requiere memoria adicional ni crear objetos temporales.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes dividir `lista` entre `d` porque el operador `/` es para números, debes de iterar la lista y dividir cada elemento por `d`.

Algo así:

```
lista = [x/d for x in lista]
```

Esta línea lo que hace es reasignar lista a una nueva lista que es creada utilizando cada elemento x de lista y dividiéndolo entre d.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas a esta codigo se le puede añadir para poner los decimales que quieras que salgan, si 4 o 10 decimales.

```
my_list = [300, 250, 85, 10]
divisor = 3550

my_list = list(map(lambda x: x / divisor, my_list))
print(my_list) # [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
print('{:.2f}'.format(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Las entradas del input son strings.
El int no puede cambiar a la lista completa, tiene que ser uno por uno.
Yo agregaría el int en el input para que convierta a entero en cuanto se agrega a la lista y pss ya tendrías una lista de valores tipo int que ya se pueden dividir:
int(input("Elemento para la lista: "))

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/368361)